# Show that there exist weights $w_1, w_2, w_3$ so that the integration rule $Q(f) = w_1 f(2) + w_2 f'(4) +w_3f(2)$ is exact for polynomials of order 2

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I'm using someone's notes of a worked example and trying to apply the technique on my own problem. If any knows what this is please correct me if there are any mistakes as I am purely redoing someone else's method and trying to figure out how to correctly do this.

We have 3 unknowns $w_1, w_2, w_3$ , we need to find these such that $\int_{-2}^2 f(x) dx = Q(f)$

It is equivalent to show that $\int_{-2}^2 1 dx = Q(1)$, $\int_{-2}^2 x dx = Q(x)$ and $\int_{-2}^2 x^2 dx = Q(x^2)$

since these are the basis of polynomials of order 2.

We have $f(x) = 1$, $f'(x) = 0$ implies that $f(-2) = 1$, $f'(-2) = 0$, and $f(2) = 1$, so,

$$\int_{-2}^2 1 dx = 1 = w_1 \times 1 + w_2 \times 0 + w_3 \times 1 \tag1$$

$$w_1+w_3 = 1$$

We then have $f(x) = x$ and $f'(x) = 1$ implying that $f(-2) = -2$ and $f'(-2) = 1$ and $f(2) = 1$ so,

$$\int_{-2}^2 x dx = [\frac{x^2}{2}]_b^a = 2-(-2) = 4 = w_1 \times 0 + w_2 \times 1 + w_3 \times 1 \tag2$$

$$w_2 +w_3 = 4$$

Next we have,

$f(x) = x^2$ and $f'(x) = 2x$ implies that $f(-2) = -2^2 = -4$, $f'(-2) = 2 \times -2 = -4$ and then $f(2) = 2^2 = 4$

And so,

$$\int_{-2}^2 x^2 dx = [\frac{x^3}{3}]_b^a = 0 = w_1 \times 0 + w_2 \times 0 + w_3 \times 1$$

And so,

$$w_3 = 0$$

and so we have a system

So if we solve $w_1+w_3 = 1$, $w_2+w_3 = 4$ and $w_3 = 0$, we obtain that $w_1 = 1$ $w_2 = 4$ and $w_3 = 0$

I am a little cautious about working out the weights and the method in general, can someone who has seen this before point me in the right direction or point out my mistakes?